# Include .tpl after page load

Tags: javascript, include, smarty

Hello its posible to load TPL file after page load?

some like:

```
function docReady(fn) {
// see if DOM is already available
    if (document.readyState === "complete" || document.readyState === "interactive") {
        // call on next available tick
        setTimeout(fn, 1);
    } else {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
    }
}       

docReady(function() {

   console.log("OK"); 
   {include file="modules/widgets/akj-select-menu/akj-select-menu.tpl" assign=akj_menu_content}

});
```

ITS not work couse i cant inster include smarty like this but  i just wont to show what i need. If its possible in Smarty + JS

Answer (score 0):

If your idea is **not related with request optimization** for fast page load (example menu.tpl is generate very long time and you want to load it later) - then: the simplest way would be to do like this:

```
function docReady(fn) {
// see if DOM is already available
    if (document.readyState === "complete" || document.readyState === "interactive") {
        // call on next available tick
        setTimeout(fn, 1);
    } else {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
    }
}       

docReady(function() {

   console.log("OK"); 
document.getElementById("akj_menu_content").style.display = "block";


});

<div id="akj_menu_content" style="display:none;">
{include file="modules/widgets/akj-select-menu/akj-select-menu.tpl" assign=akj_menu_content}
</div>
```

But.. if it is related with request optimization then `docReady()` you should make an ajax request for example `www.example.com/my/menu/generator` where you generate this menu in php (by `fetch` `modules/widgets/akj-select-menu/akj-select-menu.tpl` in Smarty and return it as HTML so JS can insert it to `<div id="akj_menu_content"`)

Comment: I need to optymalize speed load page.
I cant use PHP its smartweb platform. co i Have only tpl files